# trust self signed certificates from employer

Tags: permission, keychain, exchange, certificate

I manually set the permissions to each individual from my employer to Always Trust, is there a way to just Always Trust my companies self signed cert?

The biggest problem is email attachments, they come encrypted unless I Always Trust the senders cert

Comment: what is the TLS certificate set to in your email

Comment: I'm using the AirMail client, where is this at or is this in my keychain?

Comment: OS x saves all certificates in the keychain

Comment: I have updated all company related certs to Always Trust but this still doesn't fix the issue